# Fol all prime $p$, if $p\mid n^2$, then $p\mid n$. How can I argue by contradiction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Fol all prime $p$, if $p\mid n^2$, then $p\mid n$.
I want to argue by contradiction.
Assume $n$ is not multiple of $p$, then $n = kp + r$ ($p>r>0$), $n^2 = k^2 p^2 + 2 r k p + r^2$.
How can I prove $r^2$ isn't multiple of $p$?
Or assume $n$ is not multiple of $p$, how can I prove $n^2$ isn't multiple of $p$?

Comment: Do you know that $p$ is a prime by definition if $p\mid ab$ imples either $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$?

Comment: I want to argue by contradiction. The lemma is more general situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use the fact that $p$ is prime somewhere in there, as what you want is false when $p$ is not prime.  There are a couple of approaches.

**Unique factorization approach**:

You can factor $n$ as a product of primes, right?  So $n$ is equal to a product $p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_s^{e_s}$ for unique prime numbers $p_i$ and exponents $e_i \geq 1$.  What does it mean for $p$ to divide $n$?  It means that $p$ shows up in the list $p_1, ... , p_n$.  Think also about what the corresponding factorization of $n^2$ looks like: $n^2 = p_1^{2e_1} \cdots p_s^{2e_s}$.

**Greatest common divisor approach**:

Assume that $p$ divides $n^2$, but does not divide $n$.  Let $D$ be the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $p$.  It is a very well known fact (using the Euclidean algorithm, say), that there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $xn + yp = D$.  In particular, since $p$ does not divide $n$, the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $p$ is $1$.  So you have $xn + yp = 1$, and hence $xn^2 + ynp = n$.  Under your assumption that $p$ divides $n^2$, argue using this last equation that $p$ has to also divide $n$.  This yields a contradiction.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).